# I have the exception Unexpected sub-type: ExampleNameSpace.ClassB while Serializing in protobuf-net

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have the following code

```
namespace Example
{
[ProtoContract]
public class A : superclass
{
   [ProtoMember(1)]
  public string propertyA {get; set;}
  [ProtoMember(2)]
  public dictionary<string,ClassB> cartLines {get; set;}
}
[ProtoContract]
public class B : superclass
{
  [ProtoMember(1)]
  public string propertyA {get; set;}
  [ProtoMember(2)]
  public ClassA property {get; set;}
}


}
```

---

```
 using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
               
                Serializer.Serialize(stream, MyModel);
                srlData = stream.ToArray();
            }
```

- 

The Serialize method throws exception ExampleNameSpace.ClassB while Serializing in protobuf-net.

Answer (score 1):

Just like with `XmlSerializer` (`[XmlInclude]`) and `DataContractSerializer` (`[KnownType]`), the base type needs to advertise the expected sub types, so:

```cs
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(10, typeof(B))]
public class A {...}
```

The number used cannot conflict with any of the fields of `A`. Note that if you have a `C : B`, then `B` would need to advertise that via an attribute, and the number chosen cannot conflict with any of the members of `B`.

(essentially, sub-types are modelled as `oneof` optional fields that are a `message`)

(there are reasons why it is preferably to annotate the base type instead of the sub type; they aren't very interesting though)